# get contents of a cell Python

Tags: python, csv, cell

I am trying to get the contents of a cell from a csv file with a Python code.
What is wrong with my code? Can you please help me?

```
import csv

file = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\bbb222\PycharmProjects\scivalCSVs\g.csv'))
InstName = file.cell(0, 1)

print(InstName)
```

Comment: what is the output/error ?

Comment: What version of Python are you using ? Have you read the [csv documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) ? Where did you find the documentation about the `cell` attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

`cell` is not a proper attribute for a `csv.reader` object. If you want to access data by indexes, you can do the following :

```
>>> import csv
>>> file = csv.reader(open('C:\Users\bbb222\PycharmProjects\scivalCSVs\g.csv'))
>>> ar = list(data)
>>> value = ar[0][1]
```

Hope it'll be helpful.